# Where to add additional handlers to log scrapy output

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, logentries

I've got an existing Scrapy project that needs to be hooked up Logentries, such that everything it currently outputs to the console gets sent to Logentries as well. Currently I haven't touched any of the logging settings, and from what I gather its as simple as doing

```
logging.root.addHandler(LogentriesHandler(<token>))
```

but my question is, where should this go? I was thinking of putting it in the spider's **init**, but I don't know if that will work the way I want it to. Any advice?

Comment: Should work fine in a spider's init. Have you tried?

Comment: After a bit of digging I chose to shove it in an extension that runs at startup. 

Works the way I want it to, but I had to add the end-of-scrape stats myself via that one method that's called on spider close (can't remember it off the top of my head and I'm not at my work PC right now).